# Keys on keyboard occasionally are not shown in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios8

We are developing an iOS application.We encount a problem.
In our application, keys on keyboard are not shown in iOS 8 when we call the keyboard function.
This issue does not occur in iOS 7 and older versions.

Please let me know the solution of this issue.

Environment
・Device iOS version: iOS 8.1.1
・SDK：SDK 6.1
・App：32 bit application

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.
I am not able to post a screenshot because I have not gotten 10 reputations yet.
Please find the URL of dropbox below.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a4wso9u19fkj6o/IMG_0082.PNG?dl=0

Comment: For your further information, the problem is that keys on keyboard are not shown although the keyboard itself appears.

Comment: Apparently this issue may occur when the application resumes foreground from background.

Comment: how do you layout your subviews?

Answer (score 0):

There is some changes in latest xcode 
run your application (simulator) then choose

1.)Hardware Menu
2.)Keyboard - Toggle software keyboard .

Answer (score 0):

open simulator then from Menu choose Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard